# Set Status in Profile

Tags: feature-request

I would welcome a status such as 'I'm in Holiday' in the profile.

So for example, badges like 'Fanatic' would still be possible for people who can not visit the website for 100 consecutive days.
Also, the other people would know the reason why someone is not available.
Of course, this status would only be an option - maybe something like in Skype.

What do you think?

Comment: Then you're not really a fanatic are you? :)

Comment: Edit the "About me" section to include this information.

Comment: Yeah. Not sure why this needs a status - won't the "about me" text do?

Comment: Man up and *earn* that fanatic badge like the rest of us did...

Comment: Meanwhile, [Dave was answering questions from the hospital while his wife was in labor](http://stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-4731579).

Comment: @BradLarson Damn, I think that even beats my "hit the reputation cap on my wedding day" achievement.

Comment: @all: why would I get 13 downvotes just for an input for discussion?
Is this about meta.stackoverflow, getting punished for such thoughts?

Comment: @FabianBigler -- when people downvote a question on meta that makes a suggestion, that's a way of saying "No" to the suggestion.  Don't think of Meta rep the same way as StackOverflow rep.

Comment: @JacobM Ok thanks for the explanation. I'm quite new to meta.stackoverflow. How could I get rid of such downvoted questions? :)

Comment: Don't get rid of it. It's an interesting discussion and a good reminder for others about how the site is meant to work.  Like I say, you can't worry about your meta rep that way.

Comment: @JacobM OK, cheers.

Comment: Don't take the downvotes personally. You tagged the question with "feature-request" and as a result the vote count on your question indicates weather or not people want the feature, not weather or not it was a good question/topic. If you had tagged it as a discussion then it might have not gotten so downvoted. Feature-requests are literally requests made of the devs to implement a new feature.

Comment: @TravisJ thank you. Actually I tagged it as both.
Now I removed the feature-request tag (I wanted only to ask the community if it's a good idea or not).

Answer (score 19):

Firstly, you're not a proper fanatic if you don't log on whilst on holiday are you?

Secondly, someone not being available for a reason should not change your interaction with the site. You're not here to interact with specific people, it's not a social network. You shouldn't be asking specific people to answer your question, they'll answer it if they see it and want to.

Comment: You might be directing a comment at a particular person, which is obviously supported

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Is it? Oh, yes!